# BigQuery day partition expiration returning 2 days of partitioned data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 1 day partition expiration:

```
[tim@Timothys-MBP] data-exporter $ bq ls --format=pretty data_export
+-----------------------+-------+--------+------------------------------+
|        tableId        | Type  | Labels |      Time Partitioning       |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+------------------------------+
| test .                | TABLE |        | DAY (expirationMs: 86400000) |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+------------------------------+
```

I have a cron job that updates this table every morning at 3am UTC.
When I query this table I only expect the last days worth of data but both todays and yesterdays partitions are queried.

```
[tim@Timothys-MBP] data-exporter $ bq --location EU  query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM `proj.data_export.test`'
Waiting on bqjob_*** ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 2885 |
+------+
[tim@Timothys-MBP] data-exporter $ bq --location EU  query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM `proj.data_export.test` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-09-10")'
Waiting on bqjob_*** ... (2s) Current status: DONE
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 1447 |
+------+
[tim@Timothys-MBP] data-exporter $ bq --location EU  query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM `proj.data_export.test` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-09-09")'
Waiting on bqjob_*** ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 1438 |
+------+
[tim@Timothys-MBP] data-exporter $ bq --location EU  query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM `proj.data_export.test` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-09-08")'
Waiting on bqjob_*** ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+------+
| f0_  |
+------+
| 1434 |
+------+
```

What should I set as my partition expiration to only query the latest data?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run a query over a specific partition table like:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT  COUNT(id) FROM `dataset_name.table_name` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-12-11 00:00:00 UTC")'
```

Please note the **00:00:00 UTC** just after the date.